# how to display ACF select field(drop down) in my website product add page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF select field to add my locations to website. I create a ACF but I need to display that field on my web site. I used  the_field('plocation'); option to display it but its not working. Is there any other option to display my custom field in my product add page its really helpful. Please help me I'm  stuck in this problem 1 week. I put some screenshot my problem.

**This is the my ACF setting**
[image: This is the my ACF setting]

**Where I need this field**
[image: Where I need this field]

I'm really appreciate your help
thank you so much,
ashen.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found a method a to show acf select field values in a drop down box here is the code

**hope some one help this...**

**Code goes the child theme funtion.php**

```
add_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags','new_product_field',5);
function new_product_field(){ 

$field_key = "field_601141959f1ad";
        $field = get_field_object($field_key);

        if( $field )
        {
            echo '<div class="acf-task-difficulty-values">';
echo'<select class="dokan-form-control" name="plocation">';
echo'<option value="0">&#8211;Select a location&#8211</option>';
                foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
                {

                   
              echo'<option class="level-0" value=.'.$k.'>' . $v . '</option>';
                }
echo'</select>';
            echo '</div>';echo"<br>";
        }
```